# How do i resolve this error that says "cannot find symbol" in my code that wants to output an inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance

i was doing this code to practice inheritance. i have declared a class "Laptop" and tried to call it in my main code, the thing is that the main code cannot seem to read it even though the spelling was right.
[Class Laptop Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZDug.png)
[Main Class Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GyhR.png)

i tried importing the class Laptop unto my Main but it didn't work

here is the code of the class "Laptop"

```
package com.mycompany.laptop;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class Laptop {
    String brand, color;
    double size;

    void type() {
        System.out.println("Brand: " + brand);
        System.out.println("Color: " + color);
        System.out.println("Size: " + size );
    }
    
    void print(){
        System.out.println("My Laptop");
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the "Main" that tries to call the "Laptop" class

```
package com.mycompany.main;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Laptop a = new Laptop();
        
        
        System.out.println("-Inheritance-");
        a.brand = "HP";
        a.color = "Black";
        a.size = 15.7;
        
        a.print();
        a.type();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

the error was in the main that tries to call the Laptop class which is Laptop a = new Laptop();

when i hover the Laptop name it says this error,

```
"cannot find symbol

symbol: class Laptop

location: class Main"
```

edit: i have tried to import using the suggested comments below but the ide says that the package does not exist, here is the code

```
package com.mycompany.main;

/**
 *
 * 
 */

import com.mycompany.laptop.Laptop;

import com.mycompany.laptop.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Laptop a = new Laptop();
        com.mycompany.laptop.Laptop a = new com.mycompany.laptop.Laptop();
        
        System.out.println("-Inheritance-");
        a.brand = "HP";
        a.color = "Black";
        a.size = 15.7;
        
        a.print();
        a.type();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please show us how it looked when you added the Laptop import that didn't work? It'd be best if you edited it into the question.

Comment: you sure must `import com.mycompany.laptop.Laptop;`, `import com.mycompany.laptop.*;`, or use `com.mycompany.laptop.Laptop a = new com.mycompany.laptop.Laptop();`

Comment: i have tried all three but it only had this error that highlighted the "com" word. `package com.mycompany,laptop does not exist`

Comment: In which folders are the two classes? How are you compiling? Java or IDE

Comment: [mcve] please .. that is edit the the question and actually add the imports to the code you are showing (vs. stating what you did in a comment)

Comment: i have edited it already

Comment: For the [mcve], also tell us in which folders the .java files are. These must match the `package` declarations, and the compiler needs to know where to look for them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make all field public then try ...

package com.mycompany.laptop;

public class Laptop {

```
public String brand, 
public String color;
public double size;

public void type() {
    System.out.println("Brand: " + brand);
    System.out.println("Color: " + color);
    System.out.println("Size: " + size);
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println("My Laptop");
}
```

}

Comment: Here Main class and Laptop class in different package so you have add public